# What's the difference between auto_remove and remove in Docker SDK for python

Tags: python, docker

I'm learning to use docker SDK. I understand that containers need to be removed after run, otherwise requiring pruning later on. I'm see that there are two boolean flags in `client.containers.run`:

> - auto_remove (bool) – enable auto-removal of the container on daemon side when the container’s process exits.
> - remove (bool) – Remove the container when it has finished running. Default: False

What's the difference? If **auto-remove** is `on daemon side`, which side is **remove** on? Angel? Which side should I join??

---

ref: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in fact exactly that: `AutoRemove` is one of the parameters to the ["create a container" Docker API call](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ContainerCreate), but the `remove` option signals the client library to [remove the container after it exits](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/docker/models/containers.py#L828).

Setting `auto_remove: True` is probably more robust (the container will still clean itself up if the coordinator process crashes) but if the container fails with that option set then [`container.run()` won't return its stderr](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/docker/models/containers.py#L823-L826).  If you set `detach: True` to get back a `Container` object, then you can't use `remove: True` (it gets [converted to `auto_remove: True`](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/docker/models/containers.py#L788-L790)) but your code can `container.remove()` it after it's exited.

Comment: Links to source code are great when explaining! Please use permalinks next time though. :)